# MySQL триггеры: Как узнать название таблицы и поля, которое обновили/удалили, за счет чего отработал триггер

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Задача в следующем: при обновлении записи таблицы нужно создать триггер, который добавит в таблицу изменений пользователя, название таблицы, название поля, действие и время обновления.

Привожу код SQL-запроса на создание триггера:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check
AFTER UPDATE ON xyz_clients FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO xyz_changes(user, table_name, record, action, date) 
VALUES(CURRENT_USER, ???, ???, 'update', CURRENT_DATE); 
END
```

Нужно как-то получить название обновленной страницы и записи. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: ну название таблицы то вам известно, это xyz_clients, триггер же для нее создан  и вы его больше никак не получите. А что такое 'название поля' я вообще не понимаю, он же может обновить много разных полей ...

Comment: @Mike Точно, так же как он может обновить и много разных записей за один запрос UPDATE.

Comment: @VladimirPavluk Несколько записей не может, у него триггер `for each row` значит он будет выполнятся отдельно для каждой записи

Comment: Действительно, пропустил

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. в MySQL один триггер можно прицепить только к одной таблице, то ее название Вы знаете - это `xyz_clients`

С названием изменившегося поля немного сложнее. Вам нужно проверить изменилось ли данное конкретное поле

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check
AFTER UPDATE ON xyz_clients FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (NOT OLD.field1 <=> NEW.field1) THEN
    INSERT INTO xyz_changes(user, table_name, record, action, date) 
    VALUES(CURRENT_USER, 'xyz_clients', 'field1', 'update', CURRENT_DATE); 
  END IF;
  IF (NOT OLD.field2 <=> NEW.field2) THEN
    INSERT INTO xyz_changes(user, table_name, record, action, date) 
    VALUES(CURRENT_USER, 'xyz_clients', 'field2', 'update', CURRENT_DATE); 
  END IF;
  ..................
  IF (NOT OLD.fieldN <=> NEW.fieldN) THEN
    INSERT INTO xyz_changes(user, table_name, record, action, date) 
    VALUES(CURRENT_USER, 'xyz_clients', 'fieldN', 'update', CURRENT_DATE); 
  END IF;
END
```